# Cant instantiate ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

My web application crashes, when it reaches the constructor from my `ProductsBean`.

I get this error: `Can't instantiate class: beans.ProductsBean`

This is my `ProductsBean`:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProductsBean implements Serializable {

    private List<ProductBean> products;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{applicationBean}")
    private ApplicationBean applicationBean;

    private ProductBean selectedProduct;


    public ProductsBean() {
        Store store = applicationBean.getStore();

        for (String c : store.getCategories()) {
            for (Product p : store.getProductsOfCategory(c)) {
                products.add(new ProductBean(p.getProduct_id(), p.getDescription(), p.getPrice(), p.getCategoryName()));
            }
        }
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Thanx, I will read some more tutorials. Do you also have a good tutorial with a ManagedBean for CRUD operations?

Answer (score 3):

`applicationBean` is null in the constructor.

When dealing with managed beans, leave the constructor as dumb as possible (and do not use managed properties there). The logic involve those should be in a `@PostConstruct` method, the framework will execute it after the managed properties have been updated.

```
@PostConstruct
private void init(){
  Store store = applicationBean.getStore();

  for (String c : store.getCategories()) {
    for (Product p : store.getProductsOfCategory(c)) {
      products.add(new ProductBean(p.getProduct_id(), p.getDescription(), p.getPrice(), p.getCategoryName()));
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you need the setter for the managed properties

```
public void setApplicationBean(ApplicationBean applicationBean) {
  this.applicationBean = applicationBean;
}
```